# Is there an easy way using JPA/Hibernate to remove a child entity when parent is deleted without having to define a bi-directional relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

As the title says. Suppose I have the following entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

}

@Entity
@Table
public class Phone {
  @Id
  private UUID id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String number;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",  nullable = false)
  private User user;
}
```

And I don't want to define a bi-directional association - that is, I don't want to define the relation on the owner side of the relation (in the `User` entity). Is there an easy way to mark a `Phone` entity for removal if I delete its parent `User`?

Looking for something like `CascadeType.REMOVE` but on the `many` side of the relation. Is there such a setting available?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cascade = CascadeType.DELETE` and `orphanRemoval = true` in the owning side of your association.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) // ALL includes DELETE
    private List<Phone> phones;

    ...    
}
```

Comment: I don't want to define this side of the relationship though, that's the whole point of my question.

Comment: That's why downvoted? But you didn't mention it in your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, not sure who did, sorry about that. I did mention it though, it's both in the title: `without having to define a bi-directional relationship` and in the question itself: `And I don't want to define a bi-directional association`.

Comment: You won't have to put `User` in `Phone` if you do this. Only `@OneToMany` in parent side will suffice.

Comment: Fair enough, though I hoped it was clear that I wanted to have a reference to the parent from the child. I further clarified the question and upvoted your answer, but this is not what I am looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you. Although i wish i could help you find your intended solution. Take a look at this [association section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations) of hibernate user guide  if you haven't already if it helps. :)